# syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new at Ruby and programming and I am trying to write this simple function below

```
def sum_square(x=0, y, z=0)
    p x**2 + y**2 + z**2
end

sum_square(2,3)
```

and i get this error  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

I thought i could use optional argument here

Comment: You can't mix arguments with defaults and mandatory ones - the latter should always go first in the method signature. So there are 3 ways to fix this: 1) make `y` the first argument (seems a bad idea - very counter-intuitive), 2) add some default to `y` too or replace positional arguments with the keyword ones - `sum_square(x: 0, y:, z: 0)`

Comment: When you report an exception please tell us *where* it occurred as well as what it was. In this case Ruby told you that it occurred when processing the last `=` in `def sum_square(x=0, y, z=0)`. Ruby was complaining that what you wanted to do would might make method calls ambiguous. For example, would `sum_square(1,2)` mean `[x,y,z] = [1,2,0]` or `[x,y,z] = [0,1,2]`. She's pretty smart, however. As a rule, if you can figure out what is intended by a method call, it's probably OK. Suppose, for example, we had `def sum_square(x=0, y=1, z)`. Then would `sum_square(2,3)` be ambiguous?...

Comment: ...Obviously, `y` is assigned `3` and if we always supply variables having default values with the remaining arguments left-to-right, then `x` would be assigned `2` and `y` would be set to its default value of `1`. If you try that you will find Ruby in fact applies that rule. See @Tom's comments on the subject below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters with default values should be placed after parameters without default values or, as Tom Lord stated in comments, can be "placed anywhere else in the list, so long as they are all defined together". So, if you want to keep `y` mandatory it should be something like

```rb
def sum_square(y, x=0, z=0)
  p x**2 + y**2 + z**2
end
```

But it can be confusing during calls, so you can switch to keyword arguments:

```rb
def sum_square=(y, x:0, z:0)
  p x**2 + y**2 + z**2
end

# all these call are valid
sum_square(1) 
sum_square(1, x:2)
sum_square(1, z:2)
sum_square(1, x:2, z:3)
```

There are more possible ways to implement this function listed in comments with more general approach (for any number of inputs using `*`)  or with all params being named.

Comment: *"Parameters with default values must be placed after parameters without default values"* -- Technically not true, although this is by far the most normal way of using them. It's also *valid* (but very confusing!!) to place the optional arguments anywhere else in the list, so long as they are all defined *together*.

Comment: For example, this would also be a valid method: `def confusing_method(a, b=0, c=0, d, e)`

Comment: Also, in your example, I would instead opt to make **all** of these parameters named (and in a logical order), i.e. `def sum_square(x:0, y:, z:0)`

Comment: ...Or perhaps just generalise the method to take an arbitrarily long list of arguments, instead?! I.e. `def sum_square(*numbers); numbers.map { |n| n ** 2 }.sum; end`

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for the comments, I didn't know about defining optional parameters together before some mandatory params. As for the latter part, I totally agree with generalization idea, just wanted to keep answer as close to be the OPs example.

Comment: @Tom has made some very good points, in part explaining that your answer is incorrect. You need to fix that by editing, else a reader might take what you said as fact, and not read the comments.

Comment: "named params" is not really a thing. A more correct way to say it is "you should consider switching from postitional arguments to keywords arguments".